# How does CGAL get closest point and primitive

Tags: cgal

I did not get the source code, I wonder how to get the closest primitive, in fact it is a triangle, if I want to get the nearest point with another, just use their
Euler distance, but how to get the nearest primitive with specific point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the closest point and the closest primitive to a specific point, you can use the function [`closest_point_and_primitive()`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classCGAL_1_1AABB__tree.html#a1ae2a47f70d3d9511a65b8c40c8985a4) of the AABB-tree.

See a usage example [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html#title6)

Comment: THANKS, I know how to use it,  but i wonder how to judge it's the nearest primitive, computing the distance of point to a triangle face? or the distance of one specific point to the barycentric of the triangle?

Comment: it's the distance to the triangles that is minimized